My terminal prompt is "PC%" - How can I fix this?
My terminal prompt looks like this:
PC%

How can I fix this?
Here is picture of my terminal.


Actually maybe please post the output of echo $SHELL by editing your question (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1510001/edit), formatting it by selecting it and clicking on the "{}" button

echo $0 might be more definitive (there's no guarantee that the shell in the user's terminal emulator is actually their login shell)

You've not told us what OS/release you're using, as the SHELL used matters

@steeldriver Fair enough, Hayk please do as steeldriver said and report back

Read man $(basename $SHELL), the "PROMPTING" section, and adjust your PS1 environment variable  (in your ~/.bashrc or equivalent).

Still not working
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:74: command not found: complete
it gives more than 10 lines like this
and terminal lines look like this after source .bashrc
[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]\u@\h:\w$
